# MySQL query to retrieve items that have an exact match in a many-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have the following tables:

```
Media:
- mediaid
- mediatitle


MediaTag:
- mediaid
- mediatag


Tag:
- tagid
- tagname
```

The following tags:

```
Tag: (1) - Public
Tag: (2) - Premium
Tag: (3) - Restricted
```

The following media with tags:

```
Media: (1) - Public
Media: (2) - Premium & Restricted
Media: (3) - Premium
Media: (4) - Restricted
Media: (5) - No tags
```

Assume that a user has permissions to see only `Public (1)` and `Restricted (3)` tags. If a media has a combination of tags that the user doesn't have explicit access to, he's not allowed to see it. If a media has no tag it's not visible at all. So the user in this case would be able to see only `Media 1` and `Media 4`.

Is it possible to write a MySQL query to retrieve the media assuming I have the user permissions in the form of an array with tag IDs `(1,3)` ?

Answer (score 2):

`JOIN` the three tables, and pass the array, that contain the tag Id's that the user has permissions to access them, to the `IN` predicate in the `WHERE` clause.

For instance for the array `[1, 3]`, you can do this:

```
SELECT m.mediatitle, t.tagname
FROM media m
INNER JOIN MediaTag mt ON m.mediaid = mt.mediaid
INNER JOIN Tag t ON mt.mediatag = t.tagid
WHERE t.id IN (1, 3);
```

**Update:** To get only the `mediatitle`s that had both tag ids (1, 3) for example, use a `GROUP BY mediatitle` with `HAVING COUNT(tagname) = 2` like so:

```
SELECT m.mediatitle
FROM media m
INNER JOIN mediaTag mt ON m.mediaid = mt.mediaid
INNER JOIN tag t ON mt.mediatag = t.tagid
WHERE t.tagid IN (1, 3)
GROUP BY m.mediatitle
HAVING COUNT(t.tagname) = 2;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/adf00/2)

Comment: Thanks. That almost works but the problem is that the query also selects Media 2 which has Premium & Restricted (tag IDs 2 & 3) for permissions for 1 & 3. The tricky part is to exclude the media where the user has permissions to some, but not all of the tags.