# Hibernate/SQL multiple join query exact match relationships

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, hql

I have two tables, A and B. A has a @ManyToMany relationship with B. My goal is to select all "A" that have exact some relationship with B. Here is simple example:

```
@Entity
class A implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;

    @ManyToMany
    public java.util.Set<B> bs = new java.util.HashSet<>();

}

@Entity
public class B implements java.io.Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer id;
}


A a_only1 = new A();
A a_only2 = new A();
A a_both = new A();

B b1 = new B();
persist(b1);
a_only1.bs.add(b1);
a_both.bs.add(b1);

B b2 = new B();
persist(b2);
a_only2.bs.add(b2);
a_both.bs.add(b2);

persist(a_only1);
persist(a_only2);
persist(a_both);

// trying to query "a_only1"
query("SELECT x FROM A x "
    + "INNER JOIN x.bs y1 "
    + "WHERE y1 = "+b1.id);
    // returns "a_only1" and "a_both"

// trying to query "a_only2"
query("SELECT x FROM A x "
    + "INNER JOIN x.bs y1 "
    + "WHERE y1 = "+b2.id);
    // returns "a_only2" and "a_both"

// trying to query "a_both"
query("SELECT x FROM A x "
    + "INNER JOIN x.bs y1 "
    + "INNER JOIN x.bs y2 "
    + "WHERE y1 = "+b1.id+" "
    + "AND y2 = "+b2.id);
    // returns "a_both" (OK)
```

The best topic I could find about it was this one: [MySQL query to retrieve items that have an exact match in a many-to-many relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253814/mysql-query-to-retrieve-items-that-have-an-exact-match-in-a-many-to-many-relatio)
I think it is not exact the same thing I want and I could not rearrange to work in HQL.

The main problem is that my query find the right relationships, but ignores the rest. I need a 100% match on relationships.

I also tried direct on SQL, but no luck.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are interested in the [[NOT] MEMBER OF HQL feature](http://thecafetechno.com/tutorials/hibernate/hql-collection-operators-is-and-member-of-example/):

Try this:

```
List result = session.createQuery(
    "select distinct x from A x, B y where y.id=:xid and y MEMBER OF a.bs"
)
.setParameter("xid", b1.id)
.list();
```

or

```
List result = session.createQuery(
    "select distinct x from A x left join a.bs with bs.id = :xid"
)
.setParameter("xid", b1.id)
.list();
```

Comment: thanks, but does not work. Still returning 2 results.

Comment: enable the SQL logging and post the actual executing SQL.

Comment: select a0_.id as id0_ from A a0_, B b1_ where b1_.id=1 and (b1_.id in (select b3_.id from A_B bs2_, B b3_ where a0_.id=bs2_.as_id and bs2_.bs_id=b3_.id))

Comment: Sometimes I forget what ugly query can JPA generate on our behaves. I will think about it, maybe a left join would do the trick.

Comment: I got this. Not sure if the best, but works: "SELECT x FROM A x INNER JOIN x.bs y1 WHERE y1 = :bid AND size(x.bs) = 1" now, if I have more relations, I can just add another join and increase size to fit the inner join number.

Comment: I updated my response and added another one. Using left join and the with clause allows you to fetch A even when there is no B entry in A.bs. Using inner join you will never get any result unless you also have something in A.bs.

Comment: Let's see if the distinct keyword would help. I updated my response containing that one too.

Comment: still nothing :( Got 2 results from both

Comment: So you get two different A entities that contain the same B entity. Try running the actual SQL, since this is a many to many, you could have two A mapped to the same B.

Answer (score 0):

I got this. Not sure if the best, but works:

```
SELECT x FROM A x INNER JOIN x.bs y1 WHERE y1 = :bid AND size(x.bs) = 1
```

Now, if I have more relations, I can just add another join and increase size to fit the inner join number.

-- EDIT!

I think this one is a better solution:

```
em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM A x "
                + "WHERE :listB in elements(x.bs) "
                + "AND length(:listB) = size(x.bs)"
                ).setParameter("listB", listOfB).getResultList();
```

But does not work if I add more than one element in listOfB. How could I fix it?